# Update multiple rows in table with values from a temporary table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a database migration script to add a column to a table that contains existing data, and then populate that column with appropriate data.

I'm doing the migration in a few steps. I've created a temporary table that contains a single column with ids like this:

```
new_column
==========
1000
1001
1002
1003
...
```

I now want to update my existing table so that each row in the temporary table above is used to update each row in my existing table. The existing table looks like this:

```
old_column_1 | old_column_2 | new_column
========================================
1            | 100          | null
2            | 101          | null
3            | 102          | null
...
```

I've tried a few variations of this sort of update -

```
select min(t.new_column) 
from temp t 
where t.new_column not in (select new_column from existing_table);
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax right...

Comment: Please explain which value from the temp table should be assigned to which row in the old table ? Why does the query uses `min` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is more complicated than you think. There's nothing reliable to join on. So, either you write a stored procedure which uses a cursor to loop through both tables and updating the existing table row by row (which can quickly become a performance nightmare, therefore I wouldn't recommend it) or you use this a little complicated query:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
    (id int auto_increment primary key, `new_column` int)
;

INSERT INTO temp
    (`new_column`)
VALUES
    (1000),
    (1001),
    (1002),
    (1003)
;



CREATE TABLE existing
    (`old_column_1` int, `old_column_2` int, `new_column` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO existing
    (`old_column_1`, `old_column_2`, `new_column`)
VALUES
    (1, 100, NULL),
    (2, 101, NULL),
    (3, 102, NULL)
;

update 
existing e 
inner join (
  select * from (
    select
    t.*
    from temp t
  )t
  inner join
  (
    select
    e.old_column_1, e.old_column_2,
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 as rn
    from existing e
    , (select @rownum:=0) vars
  )e on t.id = e.rn
) sq on sq.old_column_1 = e.old_column_1 and sq.old_column_2 = e.old_column_2
set e.new_column = sq.new_column;
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fec62/2/0)</kbd>

I added an auto_increment column in your temporary table. Either you do it this way, or you simulate a rownumber like I did here:

```
    select
    e.old_column_1, e.old_column_2,
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 as rn
    from existing e
    , (select @rownum:=0) vars
```

If you want to influence which row gets which row number, you can use `ORDER BY whatever_column ASC|DESC` in there.

So, what the query basically does, is, to create a row number in your existing table and join it via this column and the auto_increment column in the temporary table. Then I join this subquery again to the existing table, so that we can easily copy the column from temporary table to existing table.

Comment: Hi @fancypants - thanks for the reply & apologies for the delay! I got dragged off onto another project for a couple of days but I'm going to try this out this afternoon.